# What happens to a message encrypted with an asymmetric key if it arrives corrupted?

Tags: public-key-encryption

I have a theoretical doubt about encryption that I couldn’t find clarified in any of the resources I have.  I’d really appreciate anyone clarifying this little doubt for me.

I’m studying Asymmetric encryption and I’d like to know what would happen if, for example, a recipient receives a message encrypted with a private key and the message gets corrupted in the way, such as due to electric interference.

My doubt is what would happen when the recipient decrypts the message: I guess the message either wouldn’t be decrypted (so you’d get an error) or it would be decrypted to an unintelligible message.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking a purely theoretical question, the answer is "It depends on the encryption algorithm".

However, in practice:

1. Messages are usually *not* encrypted with an asymmetric key. They are usually far too long for that. Instead, a short "session key" is encrypted using an asymmetric key, and the entire message is encrypted with that session key using symmetric AES or similar.

   If the asymmetrically-encrypted session key becomes damaged, the entire message is completely undecryptable (at best it would result in 100% garbage and 0% original data).

   If the symmetrically-encrypted message data becomes damaged, the result depends on the cipher mode that was used (e.g. for block ciphers CBC or CTR or GCM or other). The earlier blocks will be decrypted, the damaged block will be garbage, and the following blocks *may or may not* be garbage depending on the mode.
2. Most widely used encryption systems also include some form of integrity protection against *deliberate* tampering, which also works against regular data corruption as well. For example, AEAD ciphers, or a separate HMAC, or something like PGP's "MDC".

   If this integrity tag is present, the program will usually completely refuse to return a message that it determines was corrupted, because it doesn't know the cause of the corruption.

Comment: Clarified, many thanks.